# Отправка текста из checkbox на почту

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email

Существует html-код

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value = "80">Квартира
```

Каким образом посредством Javascript возможно осуществить передачу текста в checkbox на email?

Comment: "передачу текста в checkbox на email" - уточните, что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Из атрибута value имеется в виду. Чтобы пользователь, выбрав нужное из списка чекбоксов, мог при нажатии на кнопку отправить все выбранное на email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости как вы соберайте все поля формы, но `value` можно забрать так на нативном:

```js
function submitForm() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
  document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("z").innerHTML += inputs[i].value + ", ";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" class="x" value="80">Квартира
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" class="x" value="100">Квартира1
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" class="x" value="120">Квартира2
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk4" class="x" value="130">Квартира3
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="submitForm();">
</form>
<br>
<span id="z"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, для оперирования данными `input.val()`:

```js
var 
    input = $('input'),
    lb = input.next('label'),
    ch = input.val(),    
    text = lb.text();

console.log(ch + ' ' + text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value = "80">
  <label for="chk1">Квартира</label>
  
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

В Вашем случае, самое простое:

**html:**

```
<form>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value = "80">
  <label for="chk1">Квартира</label>

  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

**js:**

```
function submitForm(){
  var str = form.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'contacts.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: str
  }).done(function(msg){

  if(msg === "OK"){        
    console.log('ok');
  }else {
    console.log('Some error');
  }                    

  }).always(function(){

  });
}

$(document).on('submit', 'form', this.submitForm);
```

**php:**

```
<?php

    define("CONTACT_FORM", 'yourmail@gmail.com');

    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

    if($post){

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $subject = 'Тема';
        $error = '';    
        $message = '
            <html>
                    <head>
                            <title>Тема</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                            <p>Имя: '.$name.'</p>
                            <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
                    </body>
            </html>';

        if(!$error){
            $mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $subject, $message,
                 "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
                ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
                ."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"
                ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

            if($mail){
                echo "OK";
            }
        }else{
            echo '<div class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</div>';
        }

    }
?>
```

И ищите "**форма обратной связи**", примеров уже достаточно в интернете.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Буду пробовать.